# Can't make class-based RedirectView work

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm currently trying to migrate my function based views for the new django 1.3 class-based views. To start, I changed a simple RedirectView I had, but I cant get it to work, even worst, I can't understand how the class view works. The mechanism is simple, I have a select field in the index page, the user select an option and clicks "go". The view must get the url corresdponding to that name and redirect there.

When sending the POST signal, django doesn't return anything, just a 405 error in the terminal.

**UPDATED** code:

index.html

```
[...]
<div id="widget">
  <h2>{% trans "Spaces list" %}</h2><br />
    <form method="post" action="/spaces/go/">{% csrf_token %}
      <select name="spaces">
        {% for space in spaces %}
          <option>{{ space.name }}</option>
        {% empty %}
          <option>{% trans "No spaces" %}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Go' %}" />
    </form>
</div>
[...]
```

views.py

```
class GoToSpace(RedirectView):
    url = "/spaces/"

    def get_redirect_url(self, **kwargs):
        self.place = get_object_or_404(Space, name = self.request.POST['spaces'])
        return self.place.url
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from e_cidadania.apps.spaces.views import GoToSpace

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^go/', GoToSpace.as_view()),

)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What about your urls.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

RedirectView in django 1.3 **only** accepts GET requests, I was doing a POST (as recommended in django 1.2.x)

This issue was fixed for django 1.3.x (ticket [#15739](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15739))

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a class-based view in urls.py just by referencing the name of the class. As is [well documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage), you need to call the classmethod `as_view`:

```
 (r'^go/', go_to_space.as_view()),
```

You should really follow PEP8 and make your class name GoToSpace, which would make the difference from a function more obvious.

Also, `get_redirect_url` is a method, so it should have `self` as the first positional argument.

Comment: About PEP8 I know it, but as I was doing a test I didn't mind. Thing is I would probably forget changing the name afterwards. Thanks for reminding. I'll test the code in a few minutes :)

Comment: Testing the code gives me a 405 error :S I'll update the question with the new code